# best practice for getting polymoprhic behavior for one data member of an abstract base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, raii

I would like to know what would be a good approach, from a software design standpoint, to a situation where each derived class should have a different type of **polymorphic** data member. In more detail:

I'm writing a library that has an abstract base class `Base` that users of the library will inherit from. for one member of `Base`, let's call it `BaseMember`, I want polymorphic behavior. What I mean by that is that various classes derived from `Base` will "contain" different subclasses of `BaseMember` - some will contain a `OneDerivedMember`, others will contain `AnotherDerivedMember` etc (all of these are derived from `BaseMember`, and all are supplied in the library). The reason for wanting that, is that I want to be able to go over some collection of `Base` pointers and activate some functionality of `BaseMember` (which is implemented differently for its different derived classes).  As I understand it, I am guessing I have to make `BaseMember` a pointer. Now my questions start:

1. First of all, is all of this even a good approach or do you sense a "code smell" here? Is building it like that a common practice?

Assuming the basic approach is OK:

2. Where would be the proper location to allocate the `BaseMember` pointer? in the constructors of the various derived classes?
3. Can I enforce that the derived classes actually do this allocation? i.e. what if a user didn't understand, or forget, that they needed to allocate one kind or other of `SomeDerivedMember` and make the `BaseMember` pointer point to it? How can I force it not to compile in such a case?
4. Where should this member be released (de-allocated)? I suppose the RAII approach dictates it would be in the same scope it was allocated in (so, destructor of derived class?) but this forces every user of the library to remember to do this de-allocation. Instead, I could do it in the destructor of `Base` (i.e. in the library, not by the user) - but would this violate the RAII principle? and what if the user DID decide to de-allocate it (double delete...)?
5. Alternatively to all this, can you imagine a way to have equivalent polymorphic behavior without even using dynamic allocation? This code is for a low-level embedded MCU, Cortex M4 or similar cores and bare metal (no OS) - so I try to stay away from dynamic allocation wherever possible.

I feel this kind of situation must be be fairly common, and there would be a design pattern that solves this cleanly, however I'm not sure what that would be.

Example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

// --------------- Library.h ---------------
class BaseMember {
public:
  virtual void do_stuff() = 0;
};

class OneDerivedMember : public BaseMember {
  void do_stuff() {/* do stuff one way */}
};

class AnotherDerivedMember : public BaseMember {
  void do_stuff() {/* do stuff another way */}
};

class Base {
public:
  BaseMember* member;
  virtual ~Base() {/* delete member here or not? */}

};

// ------------- User of library ---------------
#include "Library.h"

class Derived : public Base {
public:
  Derived() {member = new OneDerivedMember;} // does it make sense to allocate member here?
  ~Derived() {delete member;} // delete here? or in Base?
};

class CluelessUserDerived : public Base {
public:
  CluelessUserDerived() {/* oh, I should have been allocating something here? didn't know */}
};

// I want to be able to do that sort of thing, which lead to the above (questionable?) design
int main() {
  list<Base*> my_list = {new Derived, new CluelessUserDerived};
  for (auto it = my_list.begin(); it != my_list.end(); it++) {
    (*it)->member->do_stuff();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try to with 4 by making `BaseMember* member;` into  `std::unique_ptr<BaseMember> member;` Ownership of the `BaseMember` is now nailed down and RAII is guaranteed.

Comment: @tinkerer do you want the user of the library to be able to implement a new behaviour of BaseMember as well or just using one of the available?

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi I thought the user would mostly use instances of pre-made BaseMember derivatives but may want to also implement their own derivative here and there. Would it help if that requirement is removed?

Comment: @user4581301 thanks for the suggestion. I've barely used smart pointers, I think I understand the mechanics but can you please explain the proper use here? specifically: can I - and more importantly, is it good practice, to keep the unique_ptr member empty (uninitialized) in `Base` and initialize it in various (user's) `Derived` classes?

Comment: Alessandro Teruzzi's answer covers the mechanics as well as I would, but I want to emphasize one point: The `: Base(m)` in the `DerivedWithSomeValue` constructor. This is a member initializer list and by far the best place to provide the `BaseMember` instance `Base` needs. You can leave it unset, `unique_ptr` will kindly default to `nullptr` for you, but if you have the information to completely initialize an object during construction, do it. That way you don't have to sprinkle tests throughout your code to make sure the object is fully initialized and safe to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT Following the suggestions of the OP, I replaced the example with a fully runnable one***

I would make the interface difficult to be misused:

```
#include <memory>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

struct BaseMember 
{
    virtual void do_stuff() 
    { 
        std::cout << "BaseMember::do_stuff" << std::endl; 
    }
    virtual ~BaseMember() {}
};

//consider declaring these two classes final 
struct YourDefaulHere : BaseMember
{
    virtual void do_stuff() 
    { 
        std::cout << "YourDefaulHere::do_stuff" << std::endl; 
    };
    virtual ~YourDefaulHere() {}        
};

class WithSomeValue : public BaseMember
{
    double f;
public:
    WithSomeValue(double v) : f(v) {}
    virtual void do_stuff() 
    { 
        std::cout << "WithSomeValue::do_stuff " << f << std::endl; 
    };
    virtual ~WithSomeValue() {}               
};

class Base {
    std::unique_ptr<BaseMember> member;
public:
    explicit Base(std::unique_ptr<BaseMember> m) : member(std::move(m)) {}
    Base() : member(std::make_unique<YourDefaulHere>()) {}
    void do_stuff() { member->do_stuff(); }
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

//in the client code

class DerivedDefaulted : public Base
{
public:
    DerivedDefaulted() {}
};

class DerivedWithSomeValue : public Base
{
public:
    DerivedWithSomeValue(std::unique_ptr<BaseMember> m) : 
    Base(std::move(m)) {}
};

int main() {
    //consider using a smart pointer here
    std::list<Base*> my_list = {
        new DerivedDefaulted(), 
        new DerivedWithSomeValue(std::make_unique<WithSomeValue>(5.0))
   };
   for (auto it = my_list.begin(); it != my_list.end(); it++) {
       (*it)->do_stuff();
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
YourDefaulHere::do_stuff
WithSomeValue::do_stuff 5
```

You can even provide a factory method to create std::unique_ptr< BaseMember >.
It worth to mention that as soon as you have complex types in the interface you should consider binary compatability between library and client code.

You have two more options to introduce polymorphic behaviour in your code.

***Pass a function***

It might not be suitable in your case, but you can simply pass std::function<void(void)> in. This will reduce coupling between BaseMember and Base.

***Compile time polymorphims***

This is used extensively in the standard library, std::string is an example of it. Part of the behavior is delegated to a class (called trait). https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits

This book from Alexandrescu goes in great details over the idea https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_C%2B%2B_Design

The book has aged a bit, some of the technique are deprecated but it is a wonderful book nevertheless.

This a small example to explain the idea:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Lock
{
    Lock() { std::cout << "Acquire lock" << std::endl; }
    ~Lock() { std::cout << "Release lock" << std::endl; }
};

struct NoAction {};

template<typename MultithreadPolicy>
struct Foo
{
    void somethingWithSharedResource()
    {
        MultithreadPolicy m;
        std::cout << "something here" << std::endl;
    }
};

typedef Foo<NoAction> NoThreadSafeFoo;
typedef Foo<Lock> LockingFoo;

int main()
{
    {
        NoThreadSafeFoo f;
        f.somethingWithSharedResource();
    }
    {
        LockingFoo f;
        f.somethingWithSharedResource();
    }
}
```

There are some limitations, most notably:

- No runtime plug-in, everything has to be known at compile time
- You have to provide the source code of your library (header only library)
- Binary size and compilation time might grow

On the other end you get better run-time performance, some of the calculation can be done a compile time with zero run-time cost and you will end up (usually) dealing with objects and references instead of pointers.

Modern C++ is certainly using template libraries more often than not (Boost is a great example).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I think I get the basic idea - should have thought about initializing Base's `member` in `Derived`'s constructor by direct call to an appropriate constructor of `Base`. I do have a problem with the mechanics now though - it does not compile... if I understand the compiler error, it says member(m) is bad because it copies a non-copyable thing (the uniqe_ptr).

Comment: The full error:

main.cpp:25:60: error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = BaseMember; _Dp = std::default_delete]’
     explicit Base(std::unique_ptr<BaseMember> m) : member(m) {}

Comment: after some reading, it seems like the proper way to pass a unique_ptr to a c'tor is as in `member(std::move(m))`. Would that be a reasonable edit to the code in your answer?

Comment: @tinkerer sure, I have updated the first example to be fully runnable